# QTreeWidget takeChild() - Qt

Tags: qt

I have a treeWidget in which I need to remove the QTreeWidgetItem's childelement.

```
QTreeWidgetItem *listing = new (ui->treeWidget);
AddChild(listing,id);
AddChild(listing,id);`// this is what i need to delete
AddChild(listing,id);
listing->takeChild(1);
```

I tried func takeChild(int index) but nothing happend

```
void AddChild(QTreeWidget *s,int id)
{
QTreeWidgetItem *_s = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
_s->setText(0,QString::number(id));
s->addChild(_s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your code,

```
QTreeWidgetItem *listing = new (ui->treeWidget);
```

should be:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *listing = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
```

and the signature of `AddChild()` functions is wrong:

```
void AddChild(QTreeWidget *s,int id)
```

should be:

```
AddChild(QTreeWidgetItem *s,int id)
```

Now the main issue why `takeChild()` is not working for you, is that you are not adding the items as children to `listing` , but you are adding them to the `treeWidget`, thus in your `AddChild()`, you should set the parent to `S` which is `listing`, So your code should be:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *listing = new QTreeWidgetItem(ui->treeWidget);
listing->setText(0, tr("Listing"));
AddChild(listing,0);
AddChild(listing,1); // this is what i need to delete
AddChild(listing,2);
listing->takeChild(1);
```

and the function AddChild()

```
void AddChild(QTreeWidgetItem *s,int id)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem *_s = new QTreeWidgetItem(s);
    _s->setText(0,QString::number(id));
    s->addChild(_s);
}
```

Comment: Thank's you! That helped